# Is it possible to query User Profile?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, query

I'm trying to show result depend upon input text

E.g. If user enter letter A, I want to show User form user profile with last name start with letter A.

so my question is Is it possible to query User Profile like we normal did in web part?

If not please suggest some better options

Comment: Like this: http://sympmarc.com/series/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365/ or this: https://www.itunity.com/article/develop-employee-directory-sharepoint-2013-1146

Answer (score 0):

How about using the search? There is already a Managed Property `LastName` you could use for that. An OOTB way would be a preconfigured SearchBox with a query similar to `LastName:{searchTerm}*`. Also you should change the result source to People Results.

The UI could be changed via DisplayTemplates, or you simply use the given one for Persons. You also have the option to add a refiner webpart which increases the usability.

Comment: But OOTB have some limitation to display users, I wan't to display 2000 users with letters last name A

Comment: Well paging / filtering is a thing nowdays since no user really wants to see that many results. 
Of course you could search with paging to get all results if you have to. 

Some reference for getting all results from search - http://www.thesharepointguide.com/sharepoint-search-how-to-return-all-results/